# Proving that a shifted self-adjoint transformation is unitary

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, self-adjoint-operators

I am studying for a test by working out some proofs, and here I have one that I can't seem to solve:

Let $T$ be a self-adjoint linear operator on an inner product space $V$. Prove that this transformation is unitary:

$$
(T + iI)(T - iI)^{-1}
$$

In case there is confusion, $(T - iI)$  is automatically invertible since $T$ being self-adjoint implies that $T$ cannot have complex eigenvalues so $(T - iI)$ is invertible.
The textbook states that we are to use a previous problem for this proof stating that

$$
|| T(x) \pm ix ||^{2} = || T(x) ||^{2} + || x ||^{2}
$$

I understand why this statement here is true, but I am not sure how this can be used to prove the statement above. I have spent time on it by trying to prove that $(T + iI)(T - iI)^{-1} [(T + iI)(T - iI)^{-1}]^{*} = I$, but I get no cancellations, so any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You do get cancellations if you bring the star inside!

Comment: @Ruy Yes, I know you can interchange the star and the inverse, but this gets me $(T + iI)(T - iI)^{-1}(T + iI)^{-1}(T - iI)$. This doesn't seem to cancel unless I can assume that these transformations can commute. They ought to commute, but I don't know if there is an easy way to show that.

Comment: Wait: these operators all commute with each other!

Comment: Correct @Ruy I see that now. thank you for the insight!